# hiding internal services from outside world to ensure the correct high-level service is being used

Tags: c#, interface, encapsulation, access-modifiers

I am working on an e-commerce website. I have advertisement entity which include both properties and photos. Properties are written to DB and photos are stored in file system.

I have created a `WriterService` in my infrastructure project, this service is responsible to save an ad... under the hood it should know that properties go to DB and photos go to file system... but this details is irrelevant to the outside world... the outside world should use `WriterService` to save an ad.

This is my writer service:

```
public class WriterService
{
    private DbWriter _dbWriter;
    private IFileWriter _fileWriter;

    // I believe I need to change the constructor in order to achieve my goal
    public WriterService(DbWriter dbWriter, IFileWriter fileWriter)
    {
        _dbWriter = dbWriter;
        _fileWriter = fileWriter;
    }

    public void WriterSomething(string text, Stream image)
    {
        _dbWriter.Write(text);
        _fileWriter.Write(image);
    }
}
```

Now in my infrastructure layer I have the implementation of `DbWriter` and `FileWriter`, `DbWriter` looks like this:

```
public DbWriter
{
    public void Write(string text) {/* write text to DB */}
}
```

`FileWriter` can have different implementations:

```
public interface IFileWriter
{
   void Write(Stream image);
}
```

Photos may be writter to local disk or AWS S3 bucket:

```
public DiskDriveWriter : IFileWriter
{
    public void Write(Stream image) {/* write image to Disk */}
}

public AWSCloudWriter : IFileWriter
{
    public void Write(Stream image) {/* write image to AWS */}
}
```

I want to enforce the outside world (other projects in my solution) to use `WriterService`, so if they want to save some images they should not directly use `AWSCloudWriter`, they would always have to do this through `WriterService`. Is it possible to enforce this?

---

### Update

I order to avoid a very long question, I have created [this code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231764/grouping-low-level-services-together-into-a-high-level-service) explaining the problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The only reason I can see for you to get a compile-time error making those classes `internal` is that they are used as types for parameters in methods which are themselves public. How do you expect for any code outside the assembly to call those methods, if the parameters they are receiving have types that aren't available to the caller? Can you just make those methods internal as well? Did you intend for those parameters to have some other type? If so, what? Please improve your question so that it's clear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: So, what's the problem? You removed the statement that if you make those classes `internal` you get a compile-time error. And that was the only thing remotely understandable as a problem statement or legitimate question. So what _is_ your question? You need to provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly **what the problem is**, and explain precisely what that code does, including **the exact text of any error messages**, and why you can't figure out a solution.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: the question is, is it possible to enforce consumers to use `WriterService` (so essentially hide `IFileWriter` from outside world)?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini what platform is this for

Comment: _"enforce consumers to use `WriterService` (so essentially hide `IFileWriter` from outside world"_ -- the `WriterService` as you've posted it here requires callers to pass an instance of `IFileWriter`. **How are callers supposed to use `WriterService` if they don't have access to the type required in order to call it?** (I mean, the compiler won't even let you create a class like that, but I hope you get my meaning...if it did, how would that even work?)

Comment: @Nkosi: ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @HoomanBahreini the focus is too much on implementation details. Abstract the writer service and have that publicly exposed. If the abstraction and implementation live in the same assembly then have that project manage registration with IoC container. that way consumer only knows about service abstraction and not its dependencies.

Comment: By the way: the usual approach to this is to provide a factory class, where the interface type (`IFileWriter` in this case) is public, but none of the implementing classes are. The factory class is public, and provides a mechanism for external code to create instances of `IFileWriter` without knowing the actual types. This _might_ work in your case, but you haven't provided any details that would allow anyone to know that for sure, never mind what exactly that factory class would look like.

Comment: I agree with @PeterDuniho suggestion.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini ASP.NET MVC 5+ or ASP.NET Core MVC ?

Comment: @Nkosi: I am using ASP.NET MVC and using ninject for DI.

Comment: Side note: the goal seem to be make life of users of you library harder - while one can easily mock an interface for tests it is hard to do so with reasonably designed class (and near impossibly with what the question seem to trying to achieve)

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I have created [this code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231764/grouping-low-level-services-together-into-a-high-level-service) showing the exact problem that I am trying to solve, please would you be able to have a look? I would be really interested to how to use a factory (that you suggested in the comments above) to improve my code.

Answer (score 2):

I used an adapter to map the intermediate class to the final AWS/Disk writers thus hiding them from the implementer.

**All of this code is in a separate class library**

IFileWriter

```
    internal interface IFileWriter
    {
        void Write(string text);
    }
```

Two classes implementing the IFileWriter

```
    internal class AWSWriter : IFileWriter
    {
        public void Write(string text)
        {
            //Write to AWS
        }
    }
```

```
    internal class DiskDriveWriter : IFileWriter
    {
        public void Write(string text)
        {
            //Write to disk
        }
    }
```

Abstract Base class for the adapter

```
    public abstract class AbstractFileWriterAdapter
    {
        internal IFileWriter FileWriter { get; set; }
    }
```

Two adapters, one for AWS and another for the DiskWriter

```
    public class AWSFileWriterAdapter: AbstractFileWriterAdapter
    {
        public AWSFileWriterAdapter()
        {
            FileWriter = new AWSWriter();
        }
    }
```

```
    public class DiskDriveWriterAdapter:AbstractFileWriterAdapter
    {
        public DiskDriveWriterAdapter()
        {
            FileWriter = new DiskDriveWriter();
        }
    }
```

WriterService

```
public class WriterService
{
    AbstractFileWriterAdapter _writer;

    public WriterService(AbstractFileWriterAdapter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }

    public void WriteMessage(string text)
    {
        _writer.FileWriter.Write(text);
    }
}
```

**Finally the calls from a different project**

```
            var awsAdapter = new AWSFileWriterAdapter();
            var service1 = new WriterService(awsAdapter);
            service1.WriteMessage("Some fancy text to AWS!!");


            var diskDriveAdapter = new DiskDriveWriterAdapter();
            var service2 = new WriterService(diskDriveAdapter);
            service2.WriteMessage("Some text to the drive!!");
```

Comment: this seems like a good approach. Is this related to adapter design pattern?

Comment: Yes, it the same idea overall.

Comment: So did you follow this approach - just curious.

Comment: This is an interesting approach and thanks for your answer...I wanted to make sure the outside world does not access the internals of `WriterService` (but this is not possible as those internal services are required in constructor parameter)... so I need to rethink my design.

Comment: Yes, I understand. The WriterService needs a way to call the abstract Write method and its the passed in class that decides how to implement it.
Good luck and I'm curious to see the end result!

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you make `IFileWriter` `internal` and the constructor for `WriterService` that takes your interface should also be made `internal`.

```
internal interface IFileWriter
```

```
internal WriterService(IFileWriter fileWriter)
```

Something like this:

```
internal interface IWriter
{
    void Write(string text);
}

internal class WriterB : IWriter
{
    public void Write(string text) { Console.WriteLine($"A is writing '{text}'"); }
}

internal class WriterA : IWriter
{
    public void Write(string text) { Console.WriteLine($"B is writing '{text}'"); }
}

public class WriterService
{
    private readonly IWriter x;

    internal WriterService(IWriter x) { this.x = x; }

    public void Write(string text) { x.Write(text); }

    public static WriterService WithA() { return new WriterService(new WriterA()); }

    public static WriterService WithB() { return new WriterService(new WriterB()); }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new WriterService(new WriterA());

        s.Write("Hello!");

        WriterService.WithA().Write("Hello again!");

        WriterService.WithB().Write("And again!");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you instantiate `WriterService` in your example? Suppose it is to be used by a class outside of the assembly it resides in (which might be a library, etc)...

Comment: What is the significance of the `internal` access modifier here? You're simply using constructor dependency injection...

Comment: You can initiate `WriterService` with a factory method. (Added example)

Comment: @CoolBots Since the implementing types are internal (the OP's desire) the constructor must be internal too.

Comment: @tymtam: Thanks for your answer.... but now class A is still visible from outside world. I wanted to see if it is possible to enforce outside world to access Class A through `WriterService`

Comment: @tymtam the question has changed slightly. it was an XY problem. recheck the updated question.

Comment: This will work as OP is requesting if you use factory methods; but you'd have to add a new factory method to the `WriterService` for every new `IWriter` implementation.