# How to use a factory to instantiate an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a factory to create a Generic service:

```
public static class AdPersisterFactory<TEntity>
    where TEntity : AdBase
{
    public static AdPersister<TEntity> Create(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        AdRepository<TEntity> adRepository = new AdRepository<TEntity>(dbContext);
        IAdImagePersister s3AdImagePersister = new S3AdImagePersister();
        AdPersister<TEntity> adPersister = new AdPersister<TEntity>(adRepository, s3AdImagePersister);
        return adPersister;
    }
}
```

I want to use ninject (version 3), how can I bind `IAdPersister` to an instance that the above factory creates... This is my DI Code:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

    // I have tried the following which does not compile
    // kernel.Bind(typeof(IAdPersister<>)).ToMethod(ctx => AdPersisterFactory<>.Create(new ApplicationDbContext())); 
 }
```

This is for an ASp.NET MVC application, so ideally I don't want to use new `ApplicationDbContext` but use the same `ApplicationDbContext` which exists in `RequestScope`.

I have also seen [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory) but I am not sure how/if I can use it in this scenario.

Comment: Are you willing to refactor to a more SOLID approach? does  `AdRepository<TEntity>` have a backing interface? If it does I see a way to create your open generic dependency

Comment: @Nkosi: Yes of course, I am happy to use an interface. This factory is my attempt to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279281/hiding-internal-services-from-outside-world-to-ensure-the-correct-high-level-ser)... I am trying to hide `AdImagePersister` and `AdRepository` from outside world, that's why I wanted to do the initialization in the factory.

Comment: I saw it more as a deign issue. The approach I showed would keep the implementation internal to what ever housed `AdImagePersister` and `AdRepository`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to refactor to a more SOLID approach and `AdRepository<TEntity>` has a backing interface like

```
public class AdRepository<TEntity> : IAdRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : AdBase {

    public AdRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) {
        //...
    }
}
```

And assuming...

```
public class AdPersister<TEntity> : IAdPersister<TEntity>
    where TEntity : AdBase {

    public AdPersister(IAdRepository<TEntity> adRepository, IAdImagePersister imagePersister) {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Then a way to create your open generic dependency would look like

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {
    kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<IAdImagePersister>().To<S3AdImagePersister>();
    //Open generic bind for repository and ad persister
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IAdRepository<>)).To(typeof(AdRepository<>));
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IAdPersister<>)).To(typeof(AdPersister<>));
}
```

Now where ever the persister is needed you simple inject the closed type as

```
ctor(IAdPersister<Foo> fooPersister)
```

And the necessary dependencies will be resolved and injected by the container.

There really is no need for that static factory.

### UPDATE

Based on comment I still advise to not have the static factory.

If you want to keep implementation details internal to your library then make the factory an instance class

```
public class AdPersisterFactory<TEntity> : IAdPersisterFactory<TEntity>
    where TEntity : AdBase {

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

    public AdPersisterFactory(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IAdPersister<TEntity> Create() {
        AdRepository<TEntity> adRepository = new AdRepository<TEntity>(dbContext);
        IAdImagePersister s3AdImagePersister = new S3AdImagePersister();
        AdPersister<TEntity> adPersister = new AdPersister<TEntity>(adRepository, s3AdImagePersister);
        return adPersister;
    }
}
```

That can be registered as an open generic in your composition root.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {
    kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();        
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IAdPersisterFactory<>)).To(typeof(AdPersisterFactory<>));

}
```

and used

```
ctor(IAdPersisterFactory<Foo> fooPersisterFactory) {
    IAdPersister<Foo> fooPersister = fooPersisterFactory.Create();

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... how would the constructor for `AdPersister` look like? I believe it should accept `IAdRepository` and `IAdImagePersister`? this way the DI code (which is presentation layer) should know about implementation of `AdRepository` and `S3ImageRepository`... The purpose of the factory was to hide the implementation from application layer... (maybe I should just not worry too much about hiding the implementation and do what you suggested) as I might be making the code overly confusing

Comment: @HoomanBahreini There may be some confusion. The `AdPersister` should only aware of the abstraction (interface) it is not aware of the  implementation of `AdRepository` and `S3ImageRepository` only the container know about what it is injecting.

Comment: Correct, but this way I cannot make `AdRepository` and `S3ImageRepository` internal (or maybe I did not understand your solution)? The DI biding is in a different project... The factory would have access to the internal classes...

Comment: They can be internal if the Register Service is defined in the same library and exposed to the consume as an extension. But it does in a way couple the library to the container.

Comment: Thanks for your help... At the moment `RegisterService` is in my web project (application layer) the implementation of those services in Infrastructure layer.  Are you suggesting that ninject `RegisterService` should go to my infrastructure project?